# WebAPI routing - how to make default routing ignore named methods?

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

Say I have those methods in a controller:

```
Get() 

[HttpGet]
FindSomeone()
```

I have a default route, and a route with actions: *routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"*.

Works fine when I call /mycontroller/FindSomeone, but fails with *multiple matching routes* error when I call GET /mycontroller/.

Is there a way to make default route to match Get() method only, and skip the FindSomeone() method?

Comment: why don't you call `/mycontroller/get`

Answer (score 0):

Declare the default `Get` action for all controllers in the main routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action ="Get" }
    );
```

Comment: This will disable everything BUT Get - I still need POST/HEAD/etc.

Comment: It won't disable anything. The other actions (POST, DELETE, Etc) will continue to work. It only defines the default action when not specified in the url.

Answer (score 0):

AttributeRouting migh work better for you in this scenario. It should be as simple as decorating the two methods with a Get Attribute,

```
[RoutePrefix("mycontroller")
public class MyController 
{
  [GET("")]
  Get() 

  [GET("FindSomeone")]
  FindSomeone()
}
```

That will make those methods available as mycontroller and mycontroller/FindSomeone.

Comment: I've looked at it, problem is when you go to GET /mycontroller/ - those 2 will conflict, since they're both GETs.